# How to do cumulative sum of array in 3 dimension by python? (for loop in 3 dimension)

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, cumsum

I have an array of three dimension

```
   x=
[[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]],
 [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]],
 [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]],
 [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]]
```

And I need cumulative sum like the following

```
   y=
[[[1, 21], [3, 28], [6, 36], [10, 45], [15, 55]],
 [[1, 21], [3, 28], [6, 36], [10, 45], [15, 55]],
 [[1, 21], [3, 28], [6, 36], [10, 45], [15, 55]],
 [[1, 21], [3, 28], [6, 36], [10, 45], [15, 55]]]
```

And I want to achieve this by using for loop and sum alone, i.e. without using any specific functions like in numpy or itertools, nor any extra temp variables.

I have tried

```
for k in range(0,1):
    for j in range(0,5):
        for i in range(0,4):
            y[i][j][k]=sum(sum(x[i][j][k] for jj in range(0,5) if jj<=j)for kk in range(0,1) if kk<=k)
```

but I got

```
   y[i][j][k]=[[[1, 12], [3, 26], [6, 42], [10, 60], [15, 80]],
 [[1, 12], [3, 26], [6, 42], [10, 60], [15, 80]],
 [[1, 12], [3, 26], [6, 42], [10, 60], [15, 80]],
 [[1, 12], [3, 26], [6, 42], [10, 60], [15, 80]]]
```

How to do for loop as per my need?

I have

```
x[0][0][0]=1
x[0][1][0]=2
x[0][2][0]=3
x[0][3][0]=4
x[0][4][0]=5
x[0][0][1]=6
x[0][1][1]=7
x[0][2][1]=8
x[0][3][1]=9
x[0][4][1]=10
```

.
.
.
.
I need to do

```
y[0][0][0]=x[0][0][0]=1
y[0][1][0]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]=3
y[0][2][0]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]=6
y[0][3][0]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]+x[0][3][0]=10
y[0][4][0]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]+x[0][3][0]+x[0][4][0]=15


y[0][0][1]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]+x[0][3][0]+x[0][4][0]+x[0][0][1]=21
y[0][1][1]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]+x[0][3][0]+x[0][4][0]+x[0][0][1]+x[0][1][1]=28
y[0][2][1]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]+x[0][3][0]+x[0][4][0]+x[0][0][1]+x[0][1][1]+x[0][2][1]=36
y[0][3][1]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]+x[0][3][0]+x[0][4][0]+x[0][0][1]+x[0][1][1]+x[0][2][1]+x[0][3][1]=45
y[0][4][1]=x[0][0][0]+x[0][1][0]+x[0][2][0]+x[0][3][0]+x[0][4][0]+x[0][0][1]+x[0][1][1]+x[0][2][1]+x[0][3][1]+x[0][4][1]=55
```

.
.
.

(Reposting my question with my exact requirements clearly)

Comment: Reposting questions is not necessarily a good idea

Comment: My previous question got closed as it is not clear, so I'm reposting it with correction as I dont know any other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the usual `cumsum` functions would put `1`, not `21`, in `y[0][0][1]` etc.
This code would do so:

```py
y=[[[0,0] for b in range(5)] for a in range(4)]
for a in range(4):
    for c in range(2):
        cum = 0
        for b in range(5):
            cum+=x[a][b][c]
            y[a][b][c] = cum
```

But if you want to get `21` simply move the `cum = 0` line outside the `c` loop

**EDIT**

To avoid the extra variable:

```py
for a in range(4):
    for c in range(2):
        y[a][0][c] = x[a][0][c]
        for b in range(1,5):
            y[a][b][c] = x[a][b][c] + y[a][b-1][c]
```

**2nd EDIT**

And to get `21` instead of `1` as the second value of the first pair:

```py
for a in range(4):
    for c in range(2):
        y[a][0][c] = x[a][0][c]
        if c==1:
            y[a][0][1] += y[a][4][0]
        for b in range(1,5):
            y[a][b][c] = x[a][b][c] + y[a][b-1][c]
```

Comment: Ok, but as I said in my question I don't want to use any other extra temp variable to achieve this. But I can use extra for loop if needed.

Comment: I need 21... As first answer by you, I moved cum=0 outside the c loop and got what I need but with extra variable. Similarly for your second answer, how to achieve 21 as per my requirement. Can you please help with it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
y = [[[0, 0] for _ in range(len(x[0]))] for _ in range(len(x))]
for lst, ylst in zip(x, y):
    for i, pair in enumerate(lst):
        ylst[i][0] = sum(a for a, _ in lst[:i+1]) 
        ylst[i][1] = sum(a for a, _ in lst) + sum(a for _, a in lst[:i+1])
```

You can achieve a processing of both cells in each sublist in a single iteration, using some modulo and floor division trickery:

```
# just a readablity helper to get values from nested list by running index
byi = lambda lst, i: lst[i%len(lst)][i//len(lst)] if i >= 0 else 0

y = [[[0, 0] for _ in range(len(x[0]))] for _ in range(len(x))]
for lst, ylst in zip(x, y):
    for i in range(2 * len(lst)):  # processes all 10 cells equally
        ylst[i%len(lst)][i//len(lst)] = byi(lst, i) + byi(ylst, i-1)
```